# Why would I let an exported pointer variable point to an unexported variable, at package level?

Tags: go, pointers, private, public

Taking the standard library `net/http` for example, the DefaultClient is defined as:

```
var DefaultClient = &Client{}
```

However, the DefaultServeMux is defined as:

```
var DefaultServeMux = &defaultServeMux
var defaultServeMux ServeMux
```

What's the point of defining two variables for one object? What benefit does it bring over a simple `var DefaultServeMux = &ServeMux{}`?

Comment: [This](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/20765) is related and _may_ be of interest to you, though I'm not sure the optimization would be "lost" if `var x = &Foo{}` was used instead. Unrelated to optimization, this pattern is used to export otherwise unexported identifiers for tests that declare a separate test package.

Comment: As an example of the pattern used to export identifiers for tests see [this](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/reflect/export_test.go#L24), it makes the unexported identifier available to [this](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/reflect/abi_test.go#L243-L247) (notice that the file declares a separate test package, i.e. `reflect_test`, which makes unexported identifiers declared in `reflect` unavailable to it)

Answer (score 3):

The `DefaultServeMux` part is an optimization done by **Brad Fitzpatrick**. I will copy and reformat the conversations between him and **Matthew Dempsky** from the [comments on the CL](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/20765):

**Matthew Dempsky:**

> To make sure I understand, the problem is that doing
>
> ```
> var x = newFoo()
> ```
>
> requires newFoo()
> to be called even if x is unused

**Brad Fitzpatrick:**

> Yes, that generates:
>
> ```
> var x *T
>
> func init() {
>   x = newFoo()
> }
> ```
>
> And the linker doesn't seem to ever remove init blocks, even if they only assign to things which are otherwise only ever read. Because maybe newFoo has side-effects too?

**Matthew Dempsky:**

> whereas
>
> ```
> var x = &y
> var y foo
> ```
>
> skips the explicit initialization code. So if x is otherwise unused, it can be dead code eliminated along with all of type foo's related code?

**Brad Fitzpatrick:**

> Yup

---

I have checked the size of the go binary compiled from the latest source code ([commit 4f4a9c7fff](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/4f4a9c7fff0b96d596c65f7997ab646b3ac42517)), and I found that the change of that commit helps a lot, but `var DefaultServeMux = &ServeMux{}` is a little better. See the table below:

| Implementation | size of the go binary |
| --- | --- |
| var DefaultServeMux = NewServeMux() | 15870476 |
| var DefaultServeMux = &defaultServeMux; var defaultServeMux ServeMux | 15864704 (-5772) |
| var DefaultServeMux = &ServeMux{} | 15864696 (-5780) |

**Update**:

I tried to find out the difference between `var DefaultServeMux = &defaultServeMux; var defaultServeMux ServeMux` and `var DefaultServeMux = &ServeMux{}` at the time when that commit was created (it's back to go1.7). <del>But I failed to compile go1.12 on my machine, so I gave up</del> (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76030876/1369400). What I have found is from go1.7 till now (devel go1.21-4f4a9c7fff), the two implementations are almost the same regarding the affect to the size of the go binary. Here is the result (my environment is `go1.20.3 linux/amd64` and I compiled the binary with `./make.bash`):

| git tag | var DefaultServeMux = &defaultServeMux var defaultServeMux ServeMux | var DefaultServeMux = &ServeMux{} | delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| go1.7 | 9966320 | 9966320 | 0 |
| go1.8 | 10081258 | 10081258 | 0 |
| go1.9 | 10381836 | 10381836 | 0 |
| go1.10 | 11320890 | 11320890 | 0 |
| go1.11 | 13032188 | 13032188 | 0 |
| go1.12 | 14576719 | 14576719 | 0 |
| go1.13 | 15083862 | 15083862 | 0 |
| go1.14 | 15323624 | 15323624 | 0 |
| go1.15 | 14272775 | 14272775 | 0 |
| go1.16 | 14068974 | 14068982 | +8 |
| go1.17 | 14022237 | 14022237 | 0 |
| go1.18 | 14545517 | 14545517 | 0 |
| go1.19 | 15302909 | 15302909 | 0 |
| go1.20 | 15579106 | 15579106 | 0 |
| 4f4a9c7fff | 15864704 | 15864696 | -8 |