# Cannot build and install go from source code from another tag

Tags: go, go-build

I am trying to build and install go from source code using this [documentation](https://go.dev/doc/install/source). This works fine when I do like the following:

```
 $ git clone https://go.googlesource.com/go goroot
 $ cd goroot
 $ git checkout master
 $ cd src
 $ ./all.bash`
```

Here I installed go from master branch. But when I checkout to another tag and try to execcute ./all.bash like following:

```
 $ git clone https://go.googlesource.com/go goroot
 $ cd goroot
 $ git checkout go1.12
 $ cd src
 $ ./all.bash`
```

this gives me the folowing error:

```
    go: cannot find main module, but found .git/config in /home/usr/goroot
    to create a module there, run:
    cd .. && go mod init`
```

I tried to do as the error message instructed i.e. go mod init , it gives me another error like the followig:

```
go: cannot determine module path for source directory /home/usr/goroot (outside GOPATH, module path must be specified)
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is out of date.

---

Installing Go from source for Go 1.4 through Go 1.20 and devel go1.21.

```
# Go1.4 make.bash uses C - gcc and libc6-dev
$ git clone https://github.com/golang/go -b release-branch.go1.4 --depth 1 ~/go1.4
$ cd ~/go1.4/src && ./make.bash 2>/dev/null

$ git clone https://github.com/golang/go -b release-branch.go1.17 --depth 1 ~/go1.17.13
$ cd ~/go1.17.13/src && ./make.bash
Building Go toolchain1 using /home/rocka2q/go1.4.
Installed Go for linux/amd64 in /home/rocka2q/go1.17.13
Installed commands in /home/rocka2q/go1.17.13/bin

$ git clone https://github.com/golang/go ~/goroot
$ cd ~/goroot/src && git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
$ cd ~/goroot/src && ./make.bash
Building Go toolchain1 using /home/rocka2q/go1.17.13.
Installed Go for linux/amd64 in /home/rocka2q/goroot
Installed commands in /home/rocka2q/goroot/bin
$ ~/goroot/bin/go version 
go version devel go1.21-0853f8caec Fri Apr 14 20:24:18 2023 +0000 linux/amd64
```

Checkout another tag.

```
$ cd ~/goroot/src && git checkout go1.12
HEAD is now at 05e77d4191 [release-branch.go1.12] go1.12
$ cd ~/goroot/src && ./make.bash
Building Go toolchain1 using /home/rocka2q/go1.4.
Installed Go for linux/amd64 in /home/rocka2q/goroot
Installed commands in /home/rocka2q/goroot/bin
$ ~/goroot/bin/go version 
go version go1.12 linux/amd64
```

Answer (score -1):

I can build go1.12 with go1.20.3 when the module mod is turned off:

```
$ go version
go version go1.20.3 linux/amd64
$ go env -w GO111MODULE=off
$ git checkout go1.12
$ cd src
$ ./all.bash
Building Go cmd/dist using /snap/go/current.
Building Go toolchain1 using /snap/go/current.
Building Go bootstrap cmd/go (go_bootstrap) using Go toolchain1.
go_asm.h:493:33: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
go_asm.h:494:39: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
go_asm.h:493:33: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
go_asm.h:494:39: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
go_asm.h:493:33: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
go_asm.h:494:39: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
go_asm.h:493:33: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
go_asm.h:494:39: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
Building Go toolchain2 using go_bootstrap and Go toolchain1.
# runtime
go_asm.h:493:33: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
go_asm.h:494:39: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
# runtime
go_asm.h:493:33: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
go_asm.h:494:39: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
# runtime
go_asm.h:493:33: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
go_asm.h:494:39: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
# runtime
go_asm.h:493:33: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
go_asm.h:494:39: 'p' exponent requires hexadecimal mantissa
Building Go toolchain3 using go_bootstrap and Go toolchain2.
Building packages and commands for linux/amd64.
```

(I got some test failures though)

---

I have tried to build go1.20 back to 1.6 with "go1.20.3 linux/amd64":

- go1.20 ~ go1.13: `./make.bash`
- go1.12 ~ go1.10:

  - turn off module mod first:`go env -w GO111MODULE=off`
  - `./make.bash`
- go1.9 ~ go 1.6:

  - turn off module mod first:`go env -w GO111MODULE=off`
  - specify `GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP` and build (my go is installed with snap): `GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/snap/go/current ./make.bash`
- go1.5:

  - `go env -w GO111MODULE=off`
  - `GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/snap/go/current ./make.bash`

    I got this error so I gave up:

    ```
    # runtime/cgo
    /usr/bin/ld: -r and -pie may not be used together
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    ```

Comment: Don't install from Snap. Use the official source. You have to go forward before you can go back.